# Instances of the same object in C++ (game programming)

Tags: c++, oop

I was wondering how to create multiple instances of the same object in C++. I have an example. Let's say I am creating a simple action game and I have an object called "Bullet". If I hit f.e. a CTRL key it causes a gunfire. So I create an instance of Bullet. The instance dies when the bullet hits something or get out of the window. But what if I have f.e. something like machine gun. It can fire many bullets in a row. So I have to create many instances of Bullet, but how can I do that? Should I at the beginning make a pointer like this

```
Bullet *pointer;
```

Then when I want to create an instance of the bullet I allocate a space in memory for one "bullet". And when I want to create next bullet I allocate more space and so on. But when a bullet "dies" I got a dead space in memory...

So I do not know how to handle this situation. I am new to OOP. I have programmed in C and now I want to learn C++ through the game programming (it is quite fun) :-). Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Use `new [type]` and `delete`

Comment: An object is an instance, so no, you can't make many instances of the same instance.

Comment: How do you manage a single bullet (object) so far?

Comment: Why not use unique_ptr or shared_ptr and not worry about calling delete on them?

Comment: @juanchopanza I think the closest thing that applies is the [Prototype Factory Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype).

Comment: Just one thing to avoid confusion: The terms "instance" and "object" are synonyma (at least in C++ there's no difference). You seem to mean "class" or "type" rather in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `std::vector<Bullet> bullets` to store all of your bullets. You are going to need all those objects anyway and `std::vector` will:

- amortize appending new objects
- allow you to [`shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) if at any point the vector became too large
- allow you to [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) a certain number of elements at the beginning, effectively creating an empty pool of objects
- keep all your objects contiguously, making everything very efficient

You may also want to try [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which has almost constant time insertion and removal.

Comment: A year is behind us and I have learnt a few things. I think set or unordered_set would be also great options if I give each bullet ID or something like that.